# Errno::ENOENT in UsersController#index carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I having some trouble on my site and cant find a solution to fix it,

Its something to do carrierwave, it was working fine before so not exactly sure whats happened.

Ive renewed both uploaders i have installed and ive reinstalled the gem too.

In the public folder where the images are stored there in 1 image but when i do Cover.count it says 11

```
Cover.destroy_all

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/nyall/Desktop/touchthisup/public/uploads/cover/picture/47/horse.jpg
from app/uploaders/cover_uploader.rb:41:in `is_landscape?'
from (irb):3
```

This is my uploader:

```
    class CoverUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
      include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

      storage :file
      # storage :fog

      def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end

      process resize_to_fit: [900, 900]

      version :landscape, if: :is_landscape? do
        process resize_to_fit: [@land_height, 250]
      end

      version :portrait, if: :is_portrait? do
        process resize_to_fit: [250, @port_width]
      end

      process :store_dimensions

      def extension_whitelist
        %w(jpg jpeg png)
      end

      def content_type_whitelist
        /image\//
      end


      private

      def store_dimensions
        if file && model
          model.width, model.height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
        end
      end

      def is_landscape? picture
        image = MiniMagick::Image.open(picture.path)
        width = image[:width]
        aspect = image[:width] / image[:height].to_f
        @land_height = aspect * width
        image[:width] > image[:height]
      end

      def is_portrait? picture
        image = MiniMagick::Image.open(picture.path)
        height = image[:height]
        aspect = image[:width] / image[:height].to_f
        @port_width = height / aspect
        image[:width] < image[:height]
      end
    end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a directory in your project like :

```
public/uploads/cover/picture/47
```

and paste a image with name `horse.jpg` in side this folder
and run try again, 
your issue is just because by mistake your public image directory is not there.

Comment: Thankyou, Do you know why that might have happened?

Comment: @johnseymour not sure, but by mistaken you have removed this public folder and when destroy action was trying to delete this file , file was not that present. thats why you were getting error `No such file or directory `